# Meaning of a regular matrix

Tags: matrices

If I multiply a vector $v$ to a regular matrix $M$ does it mean I rotate, stretch and move the vector or are there any more actions involved?

Comment: What do you mean by "regular"? Is your vector in the plane, or in some higher-dimensional space?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I mean invertable with regular

Answer (score 1):

Normally, say if $M$ is diagonalizable, one can think of $M = V^{-1}DV$ as

1. $\vec{x}_1 = V \vec{x}$ is rotating the space.
2. $\vec{x}_2 = D \vec{x}_1$ is rescaling in the newly rotated space.
3. $\vec{x}_3 = V^{-1} \vec{x}_2$ is rotating the space back to the original coordinates.

Comment: But there is no guarantee $M$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: This is a usefull information. But usually you take V as the Matrix that contains the eigenvectos in each colum. Why is this a rotation matrix?

Comment: @GerryMyerson You can interpret singular value decomposition in a similar vein, it is much more general. Even then it won't cover all cases, but it does take care of a *very* large subclass, and creates intuition to build on for the other ones.

Comment: @Adam correct, $V$ is indeed the eigenvector matrix (in which you rescale every column to be of norm $1$). Multiplication by $V$ can be seen as changing from the space in which the coordinates are given by the standard basis to the space where the coordinates are given by the eigenvalues, which are also a basis.

Comment: @gt6989b Does this mean that the action of a diagonalizable matrix can be seen as rotate the vector, scale it, and rotate it back? Isn't that the same as only scaling it?